# JS run the same function for nth instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the `function` to run for each `.item1` and `.item2`, etc **independently**. How would I go about running the function for any `nth` number of instances on a page?

```js
$("#edit-toggle").prop("checked", true);
$(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);

function editStatus() {
  $("#edit-toggle").on("change", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("new");
    toggleStatus();
  });
}

function toggleStatus() {
  if ($("#edit-toggle").is(":checked")) {
    $(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('.edit :input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).prop('required')) {
        $(this).parent().find('.indicator').addClass('animate');
      }
    });
    $(".edit :input").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}

$(".edit :input").on('keyup', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $indicator = $('.indicator', $this.parent());
  if ($this.val() == '' && $this.prop('required')) {
    $indicator.addClass('animate');
  } else {
    $indicator.removeClass('animate');
  }
});
```

```css
.edit-icon i {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"],
.edit-icon .checked {
  display: none;
  background: blue;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"],
.edit-icon .unchecked {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
  animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.checked {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
  animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.unchecked {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indicator {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.indicator.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceUp {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceUp {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <label class="edit-icon" for=edit-toggle>
  <input id="edit-toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle" onchange="toggleStatus()"/>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle unchecked"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil checked"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="edit block">
    <input class="edit-input" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" required/>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <label class="edit-icon" for=edit-toggle>
  <input id="edit-toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle" onchange="toggleStatus()"/>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle unchecked"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil checked"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="edit block">
    <input class="edit-input" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" required/>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `class` instead of `id` for repeater element and use `$(this).parent().next()` to find the next element.

If you don't know where is the input, you can use `data-input` and set related id to data attribute to get this element

```js
$(".edit-toggle").prop("checked", true);
$(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);

$('.edit-toggle').on('change', function () {
  var idInput = $(this).data('input');
  var inputEle = $('#' + idInput);
  var indicator = inputEle.next();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    inputEle.attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    if (inputEle.val() == '' && inputEle.prop('required')) {
       indicator.addClass('animate');
    } else {
      indicator.removeClass('animate');
    }

    inputEle.removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});

$(".edit :input").on('keyup', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $indicator = $('.indicator', $this.parent());
  if ($this.val() == '' && $this.prop('required')) {
    $indicator.addClass('animate');
  } else {
    $indicator.removeClass('animate');
  }
});
```

```css
.edit-icon i {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"],
.edit-icon .checked {
  display: none;
  background: blue;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"],
.edit-icon .unchecked {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
  animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.checked {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
  animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.unchecked {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indicator {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.indicator.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceUp {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceUp {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <label class="edit-icon" for="edit-toggle1">
  <input id="edit-toggle1" data-input="input-text-1" class="edit-toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle unchecked"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil checked"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="edit block">
    <input class="edit-input" id="input-text-1" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" required/>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <label class="edit-icon" for="edit-toggle2">
  <input id="edit-toggle2" data-input="input-text-2" class="edit-toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle unchecked"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil checked"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="edit block">
    <input class="edit-input" id="input-text-2" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" required/>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `.get(ntn)`

```js
$(".edit-toggle").prop("checked", true);
$(".edit :input").attr("disabled", true);

$('.edit-toggle').get().forEach(function(ele, i) {
  $(ele).on('change', function () {
  var inputEle = $($('.edit-input').get(i));
  var indicator = inputEle.next();
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    inputEle.attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    if (inputEle.val() == '' && inputEle.prop('required')) {
       indicator.addClass('animate');
    } else {
      indicator.removeClass('animate');
    }

    inputEle.removeAttr("disabled");
  }
})
});

$(".edit :input").on('keyup', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $indicator = $('.indicator', $this.parent());
  if ($this.val() == '' && $this.prop('required')) {
    $indicator.addClass('animate');
  } else {
    $indicator.removeClass('animate');
  }
});
```

```css
.edit-icon i {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"],
.edit-icon .checked {
  display: none;
  background: blue;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"],
.edit-icon .unchecked {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
  animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.checked {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
  animation: bounceUp 0.5s forwards;
}

.edit-icon input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.unchecked {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indicator {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.indicator.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceUp {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceUp {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <label class="edit-icon" for="edit-toggle1">
  <input id="edit-toggle1" data-input="input-text-1" class="edit-toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle unchecked"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil checked"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="edit block">
    <input class="edit-input" id="input-text-1" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" required/>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <label class="edit-icon" for="edit-toggle2">
  <input id="edit-toggle2" data-input="input-text-2" class="edit-toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle unchecked"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil checked"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="edit block">
    <input class="edit-input" id="input-text-2" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" required/>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tan. I can't use $(this).parent().next() because `.edit-icon` (the toggle) and .`edit-input` are not related in any way. Can we use data-attributes to connect the `toggle` to the `input`?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill: yes, we can use data-attribute. Let me update code

Comment: @KyleUnderhill: I updated my code. You can take a look

Comment: Thanks Tan. We run into problems if we add another input because we are talking to the toggle using `id`. How do we allow for `nth` number of `inputs` for one toggle?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill: Please don't use > 1 elements with the same id. It make confuse when we get element

Comment: Yes sorry I should have added more to demonstrate better. All of the inputs for each group will have the same `name`. Can we call using a unique name for each group of `inputs`?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill: I add another option for you. You can use `.get(ntn)` to get input element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170261/discussion-between-kyle-underhill-and-tan-duong).